# How to translate this SQL statement to ADF(Data Flow) Expression

Tags: t-sql, case, expression, azure-data-factory

Is there any way to translate this SQL statement into ADF expression(Window element)?

```
CASE
WHEN MAX(
        IF (cd.index = 1, cd.value, NULL) IN ('product', 'productListing')) THEN
        CASE
        WHEN MAX(
                IF (cd.index = 2,cd.value,NULL)) LIKE '%sunglasses%' THEN
                'Sunglasses'
        WHEN MAX(
                IF (cd.index = 2,cd.value,NULL)) LIKE '%glasses%' THEN
                'Glasses'
        WHEN MAX(
                IF (cd.index = 2,cd.value,NULL)) LIKE '%contact%lens%' THEN
                'Contact_Lenses'
        ELSE
                'No_Mapped'
        END
ELSE
        'No_Mapped'
END AS PageCategory
```

I tried different ways with Window element in data flow but nothing with correct result.

Thanks!!!

<------Solved----->

Solution:

```
case( 

        max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 1, value)) == 'product'), case( 
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%sunglasses%') ,'Sunglasses',
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%glasses%') ,'Glasses',
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%contact%lens%') ,'Contact_Lenses',
        toString('No_Mapped')
        ),
        max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 1, value)) == 'productListing'),case( 
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%sunglasses%') ,'Sunglasses',
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%glasses%') ,'Glasses',
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%contact%lens%') ,'Contact_Lenses',
        toString('No_Mapped')
        ),
        max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 1, 'No_Mapped')))
        )
```

Comment: This is mapping data flow where complex Json file(with o lot of hierarchies) is source, and destination is flat file.

SQL which I posted is Google Big Query

Comment: Solutions should not be part of the question, it's completely fine for you to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Petar Stojiljkovic. Posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

To translate the SQL statement into ADF expression. Below is the possible solution.

```html
case( 

        max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 1, value)) == 'product'), case( 
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%sunglasses%') ,'Sunglasses',
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%glasses%') ,'Glasses',
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%contact%lens%') ,'Contact_Lenses',
        toString('No_Mapped')
        ),
        max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 1, value)) == 'productListing'),case( 
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%sunglasses%') ,'Sunglasses',
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%glasses%') ,'Glasses',
        like( max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 2, lower(value)))), '%contact%lens%') ,'Contact_Lenses',
        toString('No_Mapped')
        ),
        max(toString(iif(toInteger(index) == 1, 'No_Mapped')))
        )
```